# Query String Filter and multiple values

Tags: web-part, query-string

I'm trying to get a query string filter to work with multiple values.  Right now, we have the QSF and a documents library that is correctly connected.  When I put in the query string, it filters the documents library.  Now I want to try passing in multiple values.  I tried changing the URL to be

```
?Filter=1&Filter=2
```

but when I look at the filter on the documents library, it is still just filtering for the value '1'.  I've set the web part to send all values underneath advanced options.  Is there anything else I need to do to send all the filter values to the other web part?

**Edit**
Here's the URL ?ProjectKeyword=AMAO1&ProjectKeyword=AMAO2

And here's what the filter looks like:
[image]

And finally the web part editor.  This was all done inside SP using the page designer.

[image]

Comment: Can you give us a screenshot of your filter? Are you using the "AND" operator?

Comment: And can you show your query string parameter filter? I'm guessing you used SharePoint Designer to achieve this?

Comment: @Mike All done just editing the page using web parts.

Comment: Try using Combine then into a single value and delimit with `;`

Comment: ProjectKeyword=AMAO1;AMAO2 returns no results.